# Access denied to some files in visual source safe 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When I tried to checkout some files via visual studio 2015.I got this message,

That is **Your source control provider encountered an access error.Do you want to switch to working offline in disconnected mode?**

I chose No and I got this error message..

**The current source control operation cannot be completed.The source control plug-in returned the following error:Access failure.**

Why was this happen??and how can I fix that??

Comment: Visual Source Safe is an old an notoriously unstable product. You can try running `VssAdmin` and see if doing "Repair" will fix the underlying storage. However sometimes VSS errors can prove irrepairable, leading to permanently lost or damaged files. If you have backups of the VSS folders you can try to restore that to a new location and see if the file you need can be accessed from there.

Answer (score 0):

*You can check the following things in your directory:*

1. Check that you have granted access rights to the directory. **Right click the dir -> Properties -> Security**
2. Check that you have granted access rights to the directory share. 
   **Right click the dir -> Properties -> Sharing Tab -> Permissions button**
3. Check in the **VSS Admin tool Tool/Options->General Tab** that the "Use network name for automatic login" option is set.

*Reference:* guide to VSS security 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289175(VS.71).aspx